# elastic search update Service software release in AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

after pressing update service software release in AWS console the following message appeared An update to release *******has been requested and is pending.
Before the update starts, you can cancel it any time."

Right now I waited for 1 day - still pending.

Any ideas how much time does it take, or do i need to do anything to move it from pending to updating, and should i expect any downtime in the update process[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnXqR.png)

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue somehow?

Answer (score 4):

I requested the `R20210426-P2` update on a Monday and it was completed on the next Saturday so roughly **6 days from request to actual update**.  It's also worth noting that the update does not show up in the `Upgrade` tab in the UI, it shows up in the `Notifications` tab with this:

> Service software update R20210426-P2 completed.

**[UPDATE 11 Jul 2021]** I just proceeded with updates on two additional domains and the updates began within 15 minutes.

**[UPDATE 17 Dec 2021 Log4J CVE]** I've had variable luck with the R20211203-P2.  One cluster updated in a few hours and one took a few days. A third I was sure I started a few days ago but it gave me the option to update today (possibly a timeout?).  I'm guessing they limit the number of concurrent updates and things are backed up. I recommend continuing to check the console but have patience, they do eventually get updated. If you have paid support, definitely open a ticket.

Comment: same issue with R20210426-P2, two days so far:
>An update to release R20211203-P2 has been requested and is pending.

Comment: Same issue for us from R20210426-P2 to R20211203-P2. The update got automatically started last Saturday, but has been stuck in "Update Requested" ever since. Interestingly, the notifications show it as complete: "12/18/2021, 8:45:41 PM Service software update R20211203-P2 completed." The domain was also stuck in the "Processing" state, which we've solved, but that hasn't affected the update unfortunately.